# b43 module loaded, but no interface showed up

Tags: wireless-networking, centos

I'm using CentOS 6.3 x86_64 on a hardware with a BCM43224 chip for wi-fi. I installed the `b43-fwcutter` module and then run `modprobe b43`, with no error messages. However, no new network interface showed up, and the return of `iwconfig` is:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`lspci -nn | grep 43224` returns:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
```

and `uname -a`:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 6 23:43:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas of how to make the wireless device work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I've just used Broadcom's own driver. It's not ideal, it taints the kernel with non-GPL stuff, but it's working (kernel-tainting is just a philosophical problem, it just has to do with licenses and has no effect whatsoever in how the driver works). I'll just have to recompile the module every time I update the kernel... oh well.

So, I got the driver from http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php, untarred it and tried to compile it (running `make` in the same directory where the file was uncompressed).

After a bunch of errors I've edited the file at `src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c` (which came with the tar file), replacing every occurrence of `KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, **)` with `0` (zero). After compiling the wl.ko module, I ran `modprobe lib80211` and then `insmod wl ; modprobe wl`, and voilà, problem solved.

To make it simpler, the commands below install the 64 bits module:

```
wget http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz
mkdir wldir
tar -xvzf hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz -C wldir
cd wldir
sed -e 's/KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, ..)/0/g' src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211.c -i
make
modprobe lib80211
insmod wl.ko
modprobe wl
```

For the 32 bits one, just replace `hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz` with `hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1):

First what comes to my mind that could be lacking is `wireless-tools` package. Check if they are installed, I don't know if CentOS puts that in standard installation packages.

You can also try to put wireless adapter online with `ifconfig wlan0 up` if it didn't work automatically.

There is one post on the other website of an user with a similar problem, could be of [help](http://2paisasbyviggy.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/how-to-enable-wireless-on-centos/)